# How long does mysqli_query('SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;',$dbc) remain active?

Tags: php, mysqli, bulkinsert

I need to set `UNIQUE_CHECKS` to 0 for a specific PHP file that has bulk insert, I just wanna know how long does it remain 0? Do I have to set `UNIQUE_CHECKS` to 1 after the bulk insert manually or it will automatically be changed to the default GLOBAL variable value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNIQUE_CHECKS` is a MySQL variable which is set per connection. The moment the connection is closed (normally at the end of the script or when using the appropriate MySQL client command), the setting has ended it's lifetime.

Next time a new connection starts, the value from MySQL configuration is taken again.

Comment: See as well [`set` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-statement.html)